# Pipe operator after conditional in elixir

Tags: elixir

```elixir
  def smallestNumber(list) do
    [head | tail] = Enum.sort(list)
    case head === 0 do
      true ->
        [tempHead | tempTail] = tail
        String.to_integer(Enum.join([tempHead | [head |  tempTail]],""))
      false -> String.to_integer(Enum.join([head | tail],""))
      end
    end
```

How could I avoid this repetition?
I would like to do something like this

```elixir
  def smallestNumber(list) do
    [head | tail] = Enum.sort(list)
    case head === 0 do
      true ->
        [tempHead | tempTail] = tail
        [tempHead | [head |  tempTail]]
      false -> [head | tail]
      end
      |> String.to_integer(Enum.join,"")
    end
```

Comment: can you give an example of the output  you're expecting for a given input

Comment: As @AlekseiMatiushkin mentioned I wanted to obtain the smallest possible number out of a list of numbers.
Example:
```smallestNumber([9,2,0,1])  would return 1029;```
```smallestNumber([0,0,0,1]) would return 1000;```
```smallestNumber([4,2,1,3]) would return 1234;```
A simple sort is not enough because the number can't start with a 0

Comment: Then my solution would not work either, the nearest would be `Enum.split_with/2` followed by sorting the tail `with {zeroes, rest} <- Enum.split_with(list, & &1 == 0), [h | t] <- Enum.sort(rest), do: [h | zeroes] ++ t, else: (_ -> list)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While all three answers here so far are correct, I see the XY Problem here: `[0, 0, 1, 2]` should be most likely sorted as `[1, 0, 0, 2]` which is not the case for any of the above.

In such a case, one should better use *recursion*.

```elixir
def sort(list, acc \\ [])

def sort([], acc), do: acc # exhausted
def sort([0 | tail], acc), do: sort(tail, [0 | acc])
def sort([any | tail], acc), do: [any | acc] ++ tail
```

now do whatever you want with the result.

---

Another way round would be to use [`Enum.split_while/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#split_while/2)

```
Enum.split_while([0, 0, 1, 2], &match?(0, &1))
```

and then remap the result.

---

Answering the exact question stated, simply use

```elixir
…
|> case do
end
|> Enum.join("") # `""` is redundant fwiw
|> String.to_integer()
```

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to achieve this would be to pipe into the two functions successively:

```elixir
    case head do
      0 ->
        [temp_head | temp_tail] = tail
        [temp_head, head | temp_tail]

      _ ->
        [head | tail]
    end
    |> Enum.join("")
    |> String.to_integer()
```

If you really want to pipe into a more complex function, you could consider [`then/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#then/2) but it wouldn't be idiomatic for this case:

```elixir
    |> then(&String.to_integer(Enum.join(&1, "")))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading the `case` statement correctly, then if the (sorted) list begins with zero, swap it with the second element; otherwise use the (sorted) list as-is.  You can break that out into a helper function

```elixir
def not_zero_first([0 | [first | list]]), do: [first | [0 | list]]
def not_zero_first(list), do: list
```

With this helper function in hand, you can have a pipeline without any conditionals or logic in it

```elixir
def smallest_number(list) do
  list
  |> Enum.sort()
  |> not_zero_first()
  |> Enum.join("")
  |> String.to_integer()
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a pipeline, I posit the following:

```
def shuffle_number(list) do
  list
  |> Enum.sort()
  |> case do
    [0 | [second_smallest | tail]] -> [second_smallest | [0 | tail]]
    passthru -> passthru
  end
  |> Enum.join("")
  |> String.to_integer()
end

IO.puts(shuffle_number([3, 4, 2, 1])) # 1234
IO.puts(shuffle_number([0, 4, 2, 1])) # 1024
```

This is a bit unusual in the pattern matching, but you can see a bit into how linked lists work: the first element is the head and everything else is the tail.  I've never done this kind of nested pattern-matching on lists before, but it is a valid way to de-structure (or to re-structure).

I *think* that's the behavior you described, but it would be helpful if you provided inputs and desired outputs.